# What's the proper way to reduce the space between the graph and the modebar in Dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm trying to live plot some data and the sidebar is getting pushed to the right too much because of the figure dimensions. What's the proper way to control that gap?
[image]

My code:

```py
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dash.dcc.Graph(id='live-graph'),
        dash.dcc.Interval(id='time', interval=250),
    ],
        style={"display": "inline-block"}
)

@app.callback(Output('live-graph', 'figure'),
          [
              Input('time', 'n_intervals')
    ]
)
def update(t):
    if t is None:
        return dash.no_update
    
    fig = go.Figure(data={'data':
                  [
                      go.Scatter3d(...),
                      go.Scatter3d(...)
            ]
        }
    )
    fig.update_layout(uirevision='constant',
                      scene_camera=camera,
                      width=2000,
                      height=2000,
                      margin=dict(l=20, r=0, t=20, b=20, pad=0),
                      scene=dict(xaxis=dict(range=[-10, 10]), yaxis=dict(range=[-10, 10]), zaxis=dict(range=[0, 3])))
    return fig
```